# LeftOuterJoin with same table - don't know how to distinguish them

Tags: subsonic, recursion

I would like to make a LeftOuterJoin between one table and same table,
but dont know how to make the distinguish them...

```
SubSonic.SqlQuery q = new Select().
        From(TABLE.Schema).
        LeftOuterJoin<TABLE>();
```

This returns me the error:
The objects "dbo.TABLE" and "dbo.TABLE" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Then I use

```
SubSonic.SqlQuery q = new Select().
        From(TABLE.Schema).
        LeftOuterJoin("TABLE as SecondTABLE", "SecondTABLE.ID","TABLE","ID");
```

But this returns me the error:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of 
        an object.
```

Comment: as I'm just guessing: TABLE.ID (same as SecondTABLE.ID in the Join statement?

Comment: yes. is a recursive relation
and don't know how to write in SubSonic the ALIAS for a table